# How can I troubleshoot and solve Javascript click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I  am trying to change the design of a rails app by reusing a wordpress design (I am changing layout, templates, CSS files and insert new JS files. I need to keep some of the old JS files due to AJAX, validation etc )

Anyway, currently checkbox clicking is not working. New design is using Jquery and some additional JS files and as you can see below; checkbox is visually replaced with a label tag and in the wordpress site; whenever label is clicked checkbox status changed to clicked by JS. However due to some reason (which I can not figure out right now), currently clicking does not change anything on my rails rendered page. (I receive no error both on rails console and chrome developer console).

[image]

here is the HTML code of the checkbox:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="fuel_Dizel">
  <label for="Dizel">Dizel</label>
</p>
```

When I removed  following CSS code I was able to access checkbox and here when I click checkbox, it is working and also changing the appearance of label box correctly as well).

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
```

[image]

I do not have much experience on JS troublshooting and I will appreciate if you can guide me how to troubleshoot and find and solve the root cause of the problem.

Comment: well your label's `for` does not match the input's `id`....

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that mistake.. Even though I can correct the label mistake; clicking the "label box" does not trigger desired result. How can I troubleshoot the JS? Would you please guide me?

Comment: There is no JavaScript here so not sure how debugging JavaScript would help. Maybe if you actually provided more CSS with a snipplet that shows the issue than we could help/

Answer (score 0):

When you use a tag "Label", you must be sure that value of attribute  "for" has the same value of the attribute "name" of the input that you want trigger

```html
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Dizel" id="fuel_Dizel">
  <label for="Dizel">Dizel</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that mistake.. Even though I can correct the label mistake; clicking the "label box" does not trigger desired result. How can I troubleshoot the JS? Would you please guide me?

Comment: It is necessary that you provide that Javascript File, how are you doing this?